# Joomla 1.5 login

Tags: joomla, authentication

I am just a newbee at joomla, have searched for help through forums for two days now. Tried to get help. I hope I will get help here?
I have joomla 1.5 registration worked fine. Then used CB 1.4 registration and login which I **uninstalled**. Now joomla login do not work no matter what I do. I installed The love factory dating component which I should think use the joomla default login and I set love factory registration. but now the joomla login from brings up a blank page with no error details just a blank page, registration brings up the page to register but does not add users to joomla user manager owever Admin get email to say a new user has registered.

Please help 
Thanks

Comment: Jayp hi, No I did not. I uninstalled Community builder and then installed the love factory but when I want to use the joomla login it's not working

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna to know that what the error is then Joomla have a great facility,

GO to Global parameter->server and select the error type = maximum level, and then refresh the page,

You will see your error.

Comment: Strange but true, I'm experiencing the same problem yet again. cant login to joomla backend or front end.